# Cannot set thread priority to real time despite using cap_sys_nice

Tags: c++, pthreads, rhel, thread-priority

I have an application that checks on POSIX environment whether thread priorities can be set to real time by calling

```
struct sched_param param;
param.sched_priority = 1;
int canSetRealTimeThreadPriority = (pthread_setschedparam(pthread_self(), SCHED_FIFO, &param) == 0);
```

On one system `system A` this works, but on another `system B` the check fails and I would like to find out why.

On both systems:

- the application is started as a `systemd` service via a service startup script.
- calling `getcap` on the binary returns among others `cap_sys_nice+eip`.
- the service script defines that the application is run by a non root user via `User=[non root user]`
- the service scripts sets `LimitRTPRIO=20`
- calling `sysctl -n kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us` returns `950000`, which should be the default
- calling `sysctl -n kernel.sched_rt_period_us`returns `1000000`, which should be the default
- `systemctl show [serviceName]` returns among others `LimitRTPRIO=20`
- calling the limits on the running process of the application (`prlimit --pid [application_pid]`) will show among others:

```
RESOURCE   DESCRIPTION                             SOFT      HARD UNITS
NICE       max nice prio allowed to raise             0         0
RTPRIO     max real-time priority                    20        20
RTTIME     timeout for real-time tasks        unlimited unlimited microsecs
```

On `system B` where it doesn't allow real time thread priorities:

- `etc/security/limits.conf` contains line

```
[non root user]    -    rtprio    20
```

- kernel version is `3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64` and OS version `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)`

On `system A` where realtime thread priorities can be set:

- kernel version is `3.10.0-957.56.1.el7.x86_64` and OS version `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo)`

When I test on `system A` and remove `cap_sys_nice+eip` from the binary via `setcap '' [binary]` I also cannot set real time thread priorities. I assume some setting on `system B` overrides the `cap_sys_nice` setting because it has a higher priority, so I wonder what that can be.

Comment: If you try adding `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`, does it work then?

Comment: An old adage: if you are using priorities to make your code work ... you are doing it wrong.

Comment: I might give CAP_SYS_ADMIN a shot, but it seems this is almost equivalent to starting with root and this should be avoided in my case.

Comment: " if you are using priorities to make your code work ... you are doing it wrong". It's not my code, so I need to find a solution without changing code here. The underlying reason for the real time thread priority check is because certain sub processes are meant to run with higher priorities, which I assume is for performance reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the reason why realtime thread priorities could not be set system wide was another service running, which had following settings in service script defined:

```
CPUShares=20
CPUQuota=500%
```

After removing these settings from the script and restarting the service, thread priorities could be set system wide again.